# When I solve this potential leak with autorelease my app crashes, why?

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks

the analyze function tells me that there is a potential leak at `mutableFetchResults` here:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) getBookmarks
{
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Bookmark" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[sortDescriptors release];
[sortDescriptor release];
NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
[request release];


if (!mutableFetchResults) {
    NSLog(@"Error with fetch: %@", error );
    return nil;
}

return mutableFetchResults ;
```

}

Like this it works, but with a leak warning.
When I use autorelease `NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];` my app crashes without an error log.
How can I find out the problem here?

```
- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {

    coreDataManager = [[CoreDataManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    bookmarks = [coreDataManager getBookmarks];
  }
return self;
}
```

Comment: How is <code>getBookmarks</code> being called?  Is there a different auto-release pool that's being called, such as from a new thread created by a UI event?

Comment: No, I didn't create another pool, just the standard one. Added getBookmaks call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retain anything you want to keep around, so your `init` method needs to retain the bookmarks:

```
bookmarks = [[coreDataManager getBookmarks] retain];
```

Then you can autorelease the `mutableFetchResults` variable before returning it.

Also, the Cocoa naming convention would have the `getBookmarks` method named `bookmarks`. :)

Comment: According to getBookmarks codes, it return a mutableCopy object.

Comment: @Toro Yes, but as I understand the question the OP would like to return an autoreleased object. That's also how it should be, so the `mutableFetchResults` variable should be autoreleased, and the `bookmarks` variable in the `init` method needs to retain it.

Comment: autorelease and retain, that's it! ;-)

Comment: But there is another problem now ! When I release bookmarks at the end of the function, the app crashes again ;-)

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons for that, but since you're specifically returning a mutable array, I'm guessing you're working on its contents in your code, rather than e.g. just listing it in a view. Is some of this code by chance releasing any of the objects in the mutable array without retaining them first?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say:

> When I use autorelease NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy]; my app crashes without an error log.

...there's no autorelease there. `mutableCopy` retains a copy of your array with a retain count of 1.

Comment: Yes, I mean when I add it. Sorry